# Jupyter (iPython) magic methods getting registered as str rather than callable

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I installed Jupyter (iPython) today and am able to bring up the Notebook in the browser and have it connect to a notebook server. I am able to execute Python code in cells as well but when I try using magic methods such as %timeit or %hist I get an error

> 'str' object is not callable

.

I printed out the magics['line'] object in the MagicsManager and it shows that the value of the  pairs of magic methods is a string rather than something callable. Why would this happen?

```
Looking for line magic timeit 
{'load': 'load', 'psource': 'psource', 'lsmagic': 'lsmagic', 'logstart': 'logstart', 'popd': 'popd', 'loadpy': 'loadpy', 'ls': <alias ls for 'ls -F --color'>, 'install_ext': 'install_ext', 'cd': 'cd', 'pastebin': 'pastebin', 'colors': 'colors', 'prun': 'prun', 'cp': <alias cp for 'cp'>, 'lk': <alias lk for 'ls -F -o --color %l | grep ^l'>, 'who_ls': 'who_ls', 'lf': <alias lf for 'ls -F -o --color %l | grep ^-'>, 'install_profiles': 'install_profiles', 'autocall': 'autocall', 'ldir': <alias ldir for 'ls -F -o --color %l | grep /$'>, 'bookmark': 'bookmark', 'connect_info': 'connect_info', 'll': <alias ll for 'ls -F -o --color'>, 'pprint': 'pprint', 'mkdir': <alias mkdir for 'mkdir'>, 'system': 'sx', 'automagic': 'automagic', 'whos': 'whos', 'rerun': 'rerun', 'rmdir': <alias rmdir for 'rmdir'>, 'save': 'save', 'tb': 'tb', 'lx': <alias lx for 'ls -F -o --color %l | grep ^-..x'>, 'more': 'less', 'pylab': 'pylab', 'pdef': 'pdef', 'killbgscripts': 'killbgscripts', 'precision': 'precision', 'quickref': 'quickref', 'pinfo': 'pinfo', 'pwd': 'pwd', 'psearch': 'psearch', 'autosave': 'autosave', 'reset': 'reset', 'magic': 'magic', 'dhist': 'dhist', 'edit': 'edit', 'logstop': 'logstop', 'gui': 'gui', 'xdel': 'xdel', 'xmode': 'xmode', 'cat': <alias cat for 'cat'>, 'alias_magic': 'alias_magic', 'store': 'store', 'man': 'man', 'recall': 'recall', 'debug': 'debug', 'logon': 'logon', 'page': 'page', 'history': 'history', 'profile': 'profile', 'logstate': 'logstate', 'ed': <IPython.core.magic.MagicAlias object at 0x7f7a7113d6d0>, 'pycat': 'pycat', 'pushd': 'pushd', 'timeit': 'timeit', 'set_env': 'set_env', 'unalias': 'unalias', 'rehashx': 'rehashx', 'hist': <IPython.core.magic.MagicAlias object at 0x7f7a7113d490>, 'install_default_config': 'install_default_config', 'mv': <alias mv for 'mv'>, 'env': 'env', 'qtconsole': 'qtconsole', 'load_ext': 'load_ext', 'rm': <alias rm for 'rm'>, 'config': 'config', 'dirs': 'dirs', 'run': 'run', 'reset_selective': 'reset_selective', 'pfile': 'pfile', 'pinfo2': 'pinfo2', 'who': 'who', 'matplotlib': 'matplotlib', 'less': 'less', 'notebook': 'notebook', 'unload_ext': 'unload_ext', 'doctest_mode': 'doctest_mode', 'sx': 'sx', 'macro': 'macro', 'clear': 'clear', 'pdb': 'pdb', 'alias': 'alias', 'logoff': 'logoff', 'reload_ext': 'reload_ext', 'time': 'time', 'sc': 'sc', 'rep': <IPython.core.magic.MagicAlias object at 0x7f7a7113d550>, 'pdoc': 'pdoc'}
built_in trap:
args= [u'']
kwargs= {}
fn= timeit <type 'str'>
str object timeit is not callable...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted all my individually installed packages and instead did the following:

1. Create pip2pi local repo on the machine with internet connectivity `pip2pi . --no-use-wheel jupyter`
2. scp-ed the zip file of the repo created in step 1 to the machine I wanted (this machine has no internet access and hence I had to use pip2pi on a different machine) (scp-ed as ipython_stuff.zip)
3. Installed using `pip install --index-url=file:///var/tmp/ipython_stuff/simple jupyter`

Running `jupyter notebook` worked this time around so I guess the problem was with either a missing dependency or an incorrect version, since I had installed all the dependencies manually, one by one. Using pip2pi circumvents the problem of not being able to use pip due to lack of internet connectivity and also ensures that all the packages with the correct versions are downloaded.